# Perl SWF::Builder fade in image

Tags: perl, actionscript, flash

I'm working on a script to create swf files with images fade in/out.

This is my code so far:

```
my %CONFIG = (
    'scriptURI' => "data.js",
    'imageFolder' => "images/",
    'outputFileName' => 'testImg.swf',
    'delay' => 3,                       # delay between images
    'fps'   => 10,
    'fadeFrame' => 10                   # 1 second fade in/out
);

sub addImgToMovie {
    my $img = shift;
    my $frameNo = shift;
    my $movie = shift;
    my $movieClip = $movie -> new_mc();
    my $jpeg = $movieClip -> new_jpeg($img);
    $jpeg -> place(Frame => 1);

    my $mc_i = $movieClip -> place(Frame => $frameNo);  

    my $onloadScript = sprintf("
        this._alpha = %d;
        this.apf = %f;
        this.frameIndex = %d;
        this.fadeOutFrameIndex = %d;
        ", 0, 100 / $CONFIG{'fadeFrame'}, 1, $CONFIG{'delay'} * $CONFIG{'fps'} - $CONFIG{'fadeFrame'});
    $mc_i -> onClipEvent('Load') -> compile($onloadScript);

    my $onEnterFrameScript = "
        this.frameIndex += 1;
        if ((this._alpha < 100) && (this.frameIndex < this.fadeOutFrameIndex)) {
            this._alpha += this.apf;
        } else if (this.frameIndex > this.fadeOutFrameIndex) {
            this._alpha -= this.apf;
        }
    ";
    $mc_i -> onClipEvent('EnterFrame') -> compile($onEnterFrameScript);
    return $movie;
}

my $movie = SWF::Builder -> new(
    FrameRate => $CONFIG{'fps'},
    FrameSize => [0, 0, 180, 163],
    BackgroundColor => 'ffffff'
);

my $img = $CONFIG{'imageFolder'} . "adimage1.jpg";
$movie = addImgToMovie($img, 1, $movie);
$movie -> save($CONFIG{'outputFileName'});
```

The script output a SWF file but it only fade in and fade out the image once, then I have a blank image.

I sort of debugged the file and figure out the frameIndex keeps increasing over and over, so I suspect onEnterFrame keeps playing, therefore the movieclip never stops.

Could anyone help me on how to resolve this issue. I'd like the movieclip to stop after the image fully fades out.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is missing the call to terminate the script once it's complete.  What happens if you do the following?

```
    my $onEnterFrameScript = "
    this.frameIndex += 1;
    if ((this._alpha < 100) && (this.frameIndex < this.fadeOutFrameIndex)) {
        this._alpha += this.apf;
    } else if (this.frameIndex > this.fadeOutFrameIndex) {
        this._alpha -= this.apf;
        if (this._alpha <= 0){
            this._visible=false;
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        }
    }
";
```

Notice the call the "delete this.onEnterFrame"

Comment: hi, I have tried that before but it didn't seem to be working,